# I can't get the categories and Hierarchies in FourSquare API

Tags: python, api, foursquare

In FourSquare site they say that the way to get all categories (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api-reference/venues/categories/) is with:

```
url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories&client_id={}&client_secret={}'.format(
                CLIENT_ID, 
                CLIENT_SECRET)
```

But I get the following error:

```
{
   "meta":{
      "code":400,
      "errorType":"invalid_auth",
      "errorDetail":"Missing access credentials. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/configuration/authentication for details.",
      "requestId":"5f0cee7ae116f90c6c725bcf"
   },
   "response":{

   }
}
```

Even tough I can make other requests and no problem is raised at all with missing access credentials. I have no idea what the problem is and I really need this json file with categories and hierarchies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL is wrong. Replace '&' with '?'.

`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories&client_id={}&client_secret={}` ->
`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories?client_id={}&client_secret={}`

Comment: They also require the version. The proper url is: 
`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories?client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}`